# как сформировать SQL запрос для получения глубины элементов (рефералов) в дереве до ограниченной глубины

Tags: mysql, sql

Нужен SQL запрос для выборки.

1) есть таблица с полями:

```
Login  | parent_Login
-----------------------
Ivan   | Andrey
Andrey | Stas
Max    | Andrey
Elena  | Ivan
Dima   | Elena
Dima2  | Stas
```

2) Нужно сделать выборку для Andrey тех, кто находится под ним и на какой глубине. Результат должен быть таким:

```
Login | parent_Login
----------------------
Ivan  | 1
Max   | 1
Elena | 2
Dima  | 3
```

интересует не бесконечная глубина, а только до 4 включительно

Comment: Посмотрите вот здесь http://www.cyberforum.ru/mysql/thread666144.html

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH RECURSIVE relatives AS (
                SELECT
                    id, login, sponsor, 0 as level, login as parent
                FROM
                    tg_users
                WHERE
                    sponsor = 'sponsorLogin'
            UNION ALL
                SELECT
                    u.id, u.login, u.sponsor, r.level + 1, r.parent
                FROM
                    tg_users u
                INNER JOIN
                    relatives r
                ON
                    u.sponsor = r.login
                WHERE
                    r.level < 4
            )
            SELECT level, count(id) FROM relatives GROUP BY level ORDER BY level
```